# How to call a function that doesn't exist yet in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme that has a plugin called Option Tree integrated in it to create a theme options panel (that plugin allows for a "theme mode" so it isn't installed as a plugin).

The Option Tree plugin allows you to access the saved data in the theme options by using this function:

```
$data_of_a_single_option = ot_get_option( 'name_of_option_field_to_retrieve', NULL );
```

I have another plugin that needs to get data saved in the theme option, but the theme (and option tree) is loaded after the plugin is, so calling the function leads to a "function does not exist" error.

Is there a way the plugin can call that function and get the data and be able to store that data in a variable?

I tried using an action like this:

```
function get_special_data() {
    $test = ot_get_option( 'test_field', NULL );
    return $test;
    var_dump( $test );
}
add_action('after_theme_setup', 'get_special_data', 2);

// then just below in same plugin
$data_from_theme = get_special_data();
```

Because I read that Option tree is loaded after_Theme_setup with a priority of 1.

By using add_action, I can see the data (var_dump outputs it correctly), but I can't get the data from inside the plugin by calling the get_special_data() function because it sends a "ot_get_option function does not exist" error.

Is there any way to do this? Or am I trying to solve the wrong problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [plugins_loaded](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded) action. That should work as long as the plugin defines that function without some other action required first to load the function.

Also, in your code example `$data_from_theme = get_special_data();` is going to execute before the action callback you're defining actually fires.